# How to connect to bokeh server through different device in same network

Tags: bokeh, bokehjs

I have a Bokeh Server running on my laptop, with a simple `bokeh serve --show myprogram.py` and I want to be able to connect to the same server with a different device that is in the same network. For starters that would be my home network, but in the end it will be my university's network (Not sure if there is a difference).
I tried finding the IP of the laptop running the bokeh server and typing it in in my other device's browser together with the port and app name, like `my_ip:5006/myprogram`, however my browsers tells me that there is no response from that server.

How can I view my server from different devices?

I tried reading through the documentation however it appears to me to only talk about access when the server is embedded on other websites.

Comment: Most likely, the `5006` port on your IP is blocked by your firewall. I don't think it has anything to do with Bokeh. E.g. try to run `python3 -m http.server 5006` and see if you can access it from another device using `http://%your_IP%:5006`.

Comment: When I run ```python3 -m http.server 5006``` it just runs for a second and then the command prompt accepts commands like normally is that expected? Apart from that I tried doing that and it still gives me the same error. I also just tried to edit my firewall to allow TCP connections on port 5006 and tried running the bokeh server and accessing it but it still wouldn't let me connect.

Comment: "then the command prompt accepts commands like normally" - it is not expected. At least, that's not how I've seen it work on many different Python3 versions. I get a `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 5006 (http://0.0.0.0:5006/) ...` message and then follows the log of all the requests that I make while the command is running.

Comment: I replaced python3 with python and then it worked. I was able to access through my own browser via localhost but I tried connecting through my phone via wifi or mobile network and both gave me the same error as before. What do I have to change in order for it to work?

Comment: The problem is still the same - it's your firewall. I'm not an expect there, so I can't really help, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on it earlier and I realised that there's more than one parameter change.
say if you were launching it locally by: python serve --show app.py

To make it visible for network devices, add the following to it.

in the end it would look like,

python serve  --allow-websocket-origin host_ip --port host_port --address "host_ip" --show app.py

I missed to add --address in the beginning and connection was refused when I  tried from other devices. So make sure to add all the above 3 parameters!

Also if websocket is not opened issue pops up : Check your firewall.
Disable it for a sanity check and then allow  the required ports later if firewall is the issue.

Ubuntu :
current firewall status: sudo ufw status
to Disable -> sudo ufw disable

Another tip to see the error : Press F12 on the browsers and it will pop up the console  where you can see logs.